# Weird Elasticsearch and Curl problem. Curl and wget can connect to elascticsearch but receives no data

Tags: php, elasticsearch, curl

Today i am having a weird problem with elasticsearch and curl. Elasticsearch is running fine but when i try to connect it with curl, it waits forever and no data returns.

I tried to get verbose output from curl, it can connect to elasticsearch, but after connect, it receives no data.

```
curl -v http://10.0.0.1:9200/_cat/indices
*   Trying 10.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1) port 9200 (#0)
> GET /_cat/indices HTTP/1.1
> Host: 10.0.0.1:9200
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1-DEV
> Accept: */*
>
```

It waits forever. Also elasticsearch php is not working as same.

**When i tried to open same url from same machine with lynx, it can get data successfully.** But when i tried to open same url with wget, it waits forever too. Curl can connect other external elasticsearch hosts without problem. Also we can connect to this elasticsearch host from other hosts without problem.

The other weird thing is, when i tried to get /_cat/health with curl or wget, they can get the data.

```
curl -v http://10.0.0.1:9200/_cat/health
*   Trying 10.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1) port 9200 (#0)
> GET /_cat/health HTTP/1.1
> Host: 10.0.0.1:9200
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1-DEV
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
< content-length: 63
< 
1545812391 11:19:51 mycluster green 2 2 382 381 0 0 0 0 - 100.0%
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host 10.0.0.1 left intact
```

There is no firewall on both machines. I tried to update curl, nothing changed. I also coudln't find any usefull information on syslog, elasticsearch logs etc.

Any idea why this happens?

This system is working perfectly for 4 months. I am having this issue since 2 days. Then i tried to upgrade system packages, rebooted the servers but nothing changed. I cleared the arp cache also.

Thank you.

Comment: we have this situtation when a node have high CPU Load or  high JVM Heap. did you restart elasticsearch service?

Comment: also search in master log for _nodes/stats failed or _cluster/stats failed.

Comment: We've found a solution for this. This is caused by network settings. When packet size increases, the connection drops.